# New Slider for images

Tags: javascript

I can build static web pages through CSS and HTML and now would like to add a image slider to my page, I mean the images that slide horizontally on their own. I dont have any understanding of JQuery nor Javascript or Ajax.

So at the moment I have an images folder uploaded to the server, in the head section I have put in to reference the Javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/slider.js"></script>
```

Now im stuck. How do I get the

```
<div>
```

tags on my HTML page to reference the Javascript to upload the images, etc etc?

Ill learn the coding bit but just dont know how it all links together.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/slider.js">
function someFunc(domObj){
 domObj.innerHtml += "<div id=\"div2\"></div>";

 document.getElementById("div1").innerHtml +="<h1>Hello Foobar World!</h1>";
}
</script> 

<body onLoad="someFunc(this)">
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
```

That would be some basic javascript. For a slider you could use javascript to continually update the style/position of divs through css.

Some css properties you may want to use are background-image background-position.

Comment: Hello Mike, Can I put the javascript in another file instead of having it on the main page like a CSS sheet?

Comment: @Steve of course you can just use <script src="URL" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Sorry Mike I may be sounding a bit slow here so if I had code like:

HTML page:

    <div id ="slider">

Comment: Sorry Mike I may be sounding a bit slow here so if I had code like:

HTML page body:

    <div id ="slider">
    <div id ="pic1><a href="gd/fgf/gsf/gdjf(folder path)/>         
    ........ (all the pics stored in a folder)</div>

HEAD

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/slider.js">
    (where the script is stored on the server)</script>

How is the Javascript called? 

I will control the presentation through CSS. I just need the pictures to be collected from the images folder and presented in the allocated space of the website with a horizontal slide and shown for a set amount of time.

Comment: Before we go any further are you sure you want to develop a slider on your own? This has been done before and you will likely be much better off using a premade one or using JQuery.

The first thing problem you will encounter is somehow figuring out how many images are in the folder you are specifying. I am not sure if this is possible with js. You may have to use server side code to post that to the html. Once you have that it would be fairly simple you can just var slider =document.getElementById("Slider"); var img = document.createElement("img"); img.src = "URL"; slider.appendChild(img);

Comment: Hello Mike,

Thankyou for your reply. Could i have a lesson on JQuery please as this will be the easier route for me. Im new to the interactivity side of things.

Comment: choose a free jquery slider and just include it in your project. http://www.aoclarkejr.com/best-free-jquery-content-image-sliders.html
Coin Slider looks good if you want a really nicely polished one. Or you can use chocoslider if you want something simple and supports older browsers

Comment: Hello Mike, im guessing these are sliders people have already written? What is JQuery exactly? is it a language you can learn? or is it Javascript?

Comment: It's a language which extends javascript. Basically it provides a bunch of extra easy to use features by mapping what you write to predefined javascript functions. It's basically just a library. It prevent's you from having to reinvent the wheel with javascript and it takes care of a lot of cross browser discrepancies as well.